# htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hell
I am trying to implement some mod_rewrite directives for a php web site I'm working on, and I can't get directives in the .htaccess file to be used.They work fine when placed in httpd.conf, so I know that mod_rewrite itself is working OK.  I've not needed to use .htaccess before, so I think the problem is there.I know there are directives handling this, and I've checked that I have:

```
AllowOverride None <= If i set it to ALL I got Internal Server error
 AccessFileName  Already in http  named .htaccess
```

And if i set

```
<Directory /home/sitename/www>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Got error in httpd says AllowOverride Not allowed here
So  any clue what do i missed to get htaccess working

Comment: maybe you have an internal server error in the first case because there is a wrong instruction in a .htaccess file. Check the error log for details.

Comment: I removed all htaccess rules and still got internal error when i set ALL to alllowoverride

Comment: right problems on a .htaccess file? error_log message?

Comment: @Marco DonJuan do you have access to your apache .conf files?

Comment: Please put http.conf and .htaccess file. AllowOverride Not allowed here happens when put that outside of directory (as my exprience NOT article)

Comment: @Death ,  you tips help me out i found 1 mistake in apache and its fixed , now htaccess respond thanks